# What are the values ​​for which the series converges?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, power-series, divergent-series

Determining the values ​​of $a$ and $b$ so that the series $\sum a_n$ converges, where 
 $$a_n=\ln n-a\ln(n+1)+b\ln(n+2)$$

Comment: As Rustyn wrote, I think that the series converges provided that a=b+1 whatever could be b >0.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici Actually the work I did is invalid unless $b$ is an integer, (I'd have to use Euler's extension of the binomial theorem) if not.

Answer (score 1):

\begin{align}
a_{n}
&=
\ln\left(n\right) - a\ln\left(n + 1\right) + b\ln\left(n + 2\right)
\\[3mm]&=
\ln\left(n\right)
-
a\left[
\ln\left(n\right) + {1 \over n} - {1 \over 2n^{2}} + \cdots
\right]
+
b
\left[
\ln\left(n\right) + {2 \over n} - {2 \over n^{2}} + \cdots
\right]
\\[3mm]&=
\left(1 - a + b\right)\ln\left(n\right)
+
\left(-a + 2b\right){1 \over n} + \left({1 \over 2}a - 2b\right){1 \over n^{2}} +
\cdots\,,
\qquad
n \gg 1
\\[5mm]&
\end{align}

$$
1 - a + b = 0\,,
\quad
- a + 2b = 0
\qquad\Longrightarrow\qquad
\color{#ff0000}{\large a = 2\,,\quad b = 1}
$$

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that $b$ is an integer,
$$\begin{multline}
a_n=\ln n-a\ln(n+1)+b\ln(n+2) = \ln\left(\frac{n(n+2)^b}{(n+1)^{a}}\right)= \\ = \ln\left(\frac{n((n+1)+1)^b}{(n+1)^{a}}\right)=\ln\left(\frac{n\sum_{k=0}^{b}{b\choose k}(n+1)^k}{(n+1)^{a}}\right).
\end{multline}$$
If $a=b+1$ then 
$$
a_n \to \ln(1) = 0.
$$
Now there is still the issue of "which" integers $b$ are acceptable. 
*Thanks to Andres Caicedo for pointing out some inconsistencies*

Comment: Why is $b$ an integer?

Comment: @AndresCaicedo Upon inspecting --- It doesn't have to be. Is there something I left out?

Comment: What does the expansion of $(n+2)^b$ that you wrote mean when $b$ is not an integer? It is not enough to replace the $b$ in the upper limit with $\infty$, as the resulting series diverges whenever $|n+1|>1$, which is the case here.

Comment: Anyway, this only gives a necessary condition: $a=b+1$. You have not shown sufficiency, which seems to me to be the interesting part.

Comment: @AndresCaicedo Well I probably should have thought about things a little more, thank you. It seems that, when $b$ is not an integer and rather some real, I could use Euler's extension of the binomial theorem to the complex numbers and perhaps make some argument there. This question has been answered already answered though, thank you for helping me realize that I typed some nonsense without thinking.

Comment: I do not know how to do this exercise I've tried but I get